# Content type : "Application/Json" issue with retrofit 2.2 while calling cake php apis

Tags: java, android, cakephp-3.0, retrofit2

My Api is accepting Content-Type application/json as headers. I set Header perfectly as mentioned in Retrofit Docs.

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("user/classes")
Call<playlist> addToPlaylist(@Body PlaylistParm parm);
```

I also tried by setting content type in authentication interceptor class:

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

   private String authToken;

    public AuthenticationInterceptor(String token) {
      this.authToken = token;
    }

  @Override
  public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
      Request original = chain.request();
      Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Content-type","application/json")
            .addHeader("Authorization", authToken);

      Request request = builder.build();
      return chain.proceed(request);

  }

}
```

But in Request Log it is Returning Content-Type txt/html.So how i should fix this issue? This api works fine in POSTMAN

[image]

[image]

I tried with all possible ways but it's not working with cake php web services.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *it's not working* - be more specific

Comment: dont you have an *accept header* ? if you have it please include it along with your other headers !!

Comment: @TimCastelijns updated my question

Comment: Looks like what you are showing in Logcat is Response log; Content-Type from nginx server.  Scroll up and see Content-Type for Request.

Comment: If you want to receive json should you add an ``Accept`` header? as in ``Accept: application/json``